# File.copyTo keeps old file name

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I try the following code to copy a selected file to the storage directory:

```
private function onAddFileClick():void
{
    m__file = new File();
    m__file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelect);
    m__file.browseForOpen("Select a sound", [c__filter]);
}

private function onFileSelect(e:Event):void 
{
    var l__target:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("test.snd");
    m__file.copyTo(l__target, true);
}
```

The copy works but the target file's name keeps the original file's name. If I try to copy a file name "Kalimba.mp3", the copy will be named "Kalimba.snd" and not "test.snd" as expected. The problem is that after the copy, my reference to the target file does not lead to anything since its `nativePath` sticks to "test.snd" which does not exist.

I use AIR 3.6 with Flex 4.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming is done with `File.moveTo()`.
copy first and then use moveTo() to rename it. Unless just moving it will do it for you! Obviously ;)

So after you copy:

```
var sourceFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
sourceFile = sourceFile.resolvePath("Kalimba.snd");
var destination:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
destination = destination.resolvePath("test.snd");

try  
{
    sourceFile.moveTo(destination, true);
}
catch (error:Error)
{
    trace("Error:" + error.message);
}
```

Comment: So copyTo is only able to rename the extension... That's sad and you're right. I would add that sourceFile keeps a reference to the unexisting pre-move file.